ZIP files containing specific texts using VBA
I am new to VBA excel and i'm working on a project where I need to zip the files containing same reference numbers. Below is the code I've found and getting an error with this section:
' Copy the selected files into the zip file
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    For Each filePath In selectedFiles
        ShellApp.Namespace(outputZip).CopyHere filePath
    Next filePath


Error: Run time error 91: Object variable or with block not set

I hope someone could help me on this project.
VBA code:
Sub ZipFilesContainingText(folderPath As String, searchText As String, outputZip As String)
Dim fso As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim file As Object
Dim selectedFiles As New Collection
Dim ShellApp As Object


' Create FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderPath)

' Loop through each file in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Check if the file contains the search text
    If InStr(1, file.Name, searchText, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        selectedFiles.Add file.Path
    End If
Next file

' Create an empty zip file
Open outputZip For Output As #1
Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
Close #1


' Copy the selected files into the zip file
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each filePath In selectedFiles
    ShellApp.Namespace(outputZip).CopyHere filePath
Next filePath

' Wait for the zipping process to complete
On Error Resume Next
Do Until ShellApp.Namespace(outputZip).items.Count = selectedFiles.Count
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Loop
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub ZipMyFiles()

Dim folderToZip As String
Dim searchText As String
Dim outputZip As String

Nxt = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(What:="", after:=Range("A1"),      searchdirection:=xlNext).Row 'defining last empty cell based from column A

For O = 2 To Nxt - 1

folderToZip = Range("C" & O).Value
searchText = Range("A" & O).Value
outputZip = Range("D" & O).Value

ZipFilesContainingText folderToZip, searchText, outputZip

Next O

End Sub


Shell doesn't like String variables, so try using Variant eg. outputZip As Variant  Also add Option Explicit and make sure all your variables are declared.
